# How to Add list Item to a class Object

Tags: c#, windows, class, xaml

I am getting the return as Task(List(object)) from an API call and I am trying to Add this list to a class object that was defined as Students But its not adding any data into my class object

My List returned will be something like this

```
[
 {
   "Name": "Something no 1",
   "Age": 20
 },
 {
   "Name": "Something no 2",
   "Age": 21
 },
 {
   "Name": "Something no 3",
   "Age": 11
 }
]
```

My Class:

```
 public class Students
 {
     public string Name;
     public int Age; 
 }

 public ObservableCollection<Students> students = new ObservableCollection<Students>();
List<object> response_list = await response;

 foreach ( var item1 in response_list)
 {
     if (item1 != null)
     {
         students.Add(item1 as Students);  
     }
 }
```

Now I tried in another way:

Since I have a class written i can directly deserialize it to my class object using NewtonSoft.json.But it also not worked.

```
  public ObservableCollection<Students> students = new ObservableCollection<Students>();
    //public int Max_width;
 string responseString = await response;

 students =     JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ObservableCollection<Students>>(responseString);
```

But this also failed

Comment: Are the objects actually of type `Student`?

Comment: I think your doubt got clarified now ... Hamlet

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
foreach ( dynamic item1 in response_list)
     {
         if (item1 != null)
         {
             discussions_cnt_new.Add(new Students() { Name = item1.Name, Age = item1.Age });  
         }
     }
```